# Make Mediawiki Tagline a link?

Tags: mediawiki

Is there a way to make the tagline in mediawiki a link to an external url? When I edit it in the MediaWiki: Tagline the entire path displays rather turning the text into a link. I assume I need to configure this in the PHP settings, but I'm just not sure where exactly I need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

As the [tagline](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Tagline_%28Site_Subtitle%29) is typically shown only on printout friendly page versions, it is does not handle links. To change this behaviour, you will need to alter your skin. In you skin, change

```
<?php $this->msg( 'tagline' ); ?>
```

to

```
<?php $this->msgWiki( 'tagline' ); ?>
```

and you should be able to use wikisyntax in the tagline, by changing the contents of `MediaWiki:Tagline` to something like:

```
From [http://www.example.net/ {{SITENAME}}]
```

Comment: Searched real hard, Googled hard, cannot find where to make that change. What file is that in? I'm using Vector. I don't see '<?php $this->msg( 'tagline' ); ?>' in any of the PHP files.

Comment: Really? What version are you using? In current version it's right there in the skin file: https://git.wikimedia.org/blob/mediawiki%2Fskins%2FVector/5d50e05f2dc8e79789c26d3849a2c91749a5ec47/VectorTemplate.php#L126